# How do I ensure that function of the sum is less than sum of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

I have any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is an increasing function.

What do I need, as a property of $f$, to ensure that $f(a+b) \leqslant f(a) + f(b)$ ?

My guess is that $f\ concave$ is not enough. Because $\ln(1.1 + 1.2) > \ln(1.1) + \ln(1.2)$. However it seems to always work with the logistic function $\lg: x \mapsto \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\beta}} + 1}$.

It must have something to see with increasing rate or the existence of a finit limit. What am I missing?

Comment: Note concave deals with average, not sum about two points

Comment: @YujieZha Yupe.. which is why it is a wrong track. What then? :\

Comment: @iago-lito $f$ is called a [subadditive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Definitions). `Because ln ...` The codomain of $\ln$ is *not* $\mathbb{R}^+\,$.

Comment: @dxiv This is the name of the property I need! Also, sorry for this mistake: I forgot to shift $\ln$ in order to make its codomain included in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Once I've done it, the function $f: x \mapsto \ln(x + 1)$ turned out to be subadditive indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One additional condition could be that $f(0)\geq 0$ and $f$ is concave then putting $y=0$ you have by concavity that $$f(tx)\geq tf(x)+(1-t)f(0)\geq tf(x)$$
Also
$$f(a)+f(b)=f\left((a+b)\frac{a}{a+b}\right)+f\left((a+b)\frac{b}{a+b}\right)\geq\frac{a}{a+b}f(a+b)+\frac{b}{a+b}f(a+b)=f(a+b)$$

Comment: Perfect ! In other words, I only need concavity since $f(y) \geqslant 0$ is guaranteed by $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$. My mistake was to forget shifting $\ln$ as an example of such a function. Cheers :)

Comment: Note: it may not be true that I "only need concavity": maybe $f$ could be subadditive without being concave (I doubt it though)..